# Attaching closet door divider to laminate

Tags: engineered-flooring

Installers of our laminate floors (over concrete) told us the could not screw into the laminate to anchor the divider without splitting it.  The glue they used has already come loose as well as the wood glue we tried. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Drill oversize holes (3/8" to 1/2" or so) just through the flooring that are still concealed by the divider's base plate, and mount the divider directly to the subfloor. You may want to use nylon or metal bushings to hold the divider at the same level as the floor (to avoid pinching the flooring), and you may need to purchase longer screws.

Use a sharp bit, ideally a "pilot point", and a high bit speed with low force. If you don't have a pilot point bit, start with about a 1/8" bit and progress up in size.

Answer (score 3):

I would drill a hole straight through the laminate and anchor the divider to the concrete underneath using something like this:
[image] or [image] or [image]

If the underlay between your laminate and the concrete subfloor is in any way compressible, you should probably add a bushing to prevent you from compressing it when securing the anchors.
The bushing should be the same height as the thickness of the underlay + the thickness of the laminate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

brhans shows a picture of the correct drill to use. Its called a "masonry bit". Tapcons are the screws to use for conrete. Some packages come with a drill bit. Also if you have to buy a drill because you don't have one, get a hammer drill. They don't actually hammer, just vibrate to help drill into concrete. A corded hammer drill is not very expensive.

Comment: And if you only have a standard drill, get a hammer drill before you start trying to drill concrete.